# Android Studio , Camera Manager turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel throw exception. How to resolve?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I'm using api 34 for my android phone galaxy.  everything was working fine until I tried to use the Camera Manager turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel.

The code:

```
package com.example.myflashlight

import android.content.Context
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.widget.SeekBar
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var cameraManager: CameraManager
    private lateinit var cameraId: String
    private lateinit var handler: Handler
    private var isFlashOn = false
    private var counter: Float = 0.0F



    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        cameraManager.turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel(cameraId, 50)

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        val seek = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)
        seek.min = 100
        seek.max = 1000
        seek.progress = 500
        counter = seek.progress.toFloat()

        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
                override fun onProgressChanged(
                    seekBar: SeekBar?,
                    progress: Int,
                    fromUser: Boolean
                ) {
                    // Log.d("seekbar", "Your Progress: ${seekBar?.progress}"

                    counter = seek.progress.toFloat()
                    val formattedString = String.format("%.0f", counter)
                    if(progress < 1000) {
                        textView.text = "Milliseconds: " + formattedString
                    }
                    else {
                        textView.text = "Milliseconds: " + formattedString
                    }
                }

                override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) = Unit
                override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) = Unit
            },
        )

        cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        try {
            cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
        } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    }
```

The error is on the line:

```
cameraManager.turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel(cameraId, 50)
```

The error from the Logcat:

2023-08-25 12:40:16.026 31724-31724 AndroidRuntime          com.example.myflashlight             E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myflashlight, PID: 31724
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myflashlight/com.example.myflashlight.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property cameraManager has not been initialized
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4169)                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)                                                                                                     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property cameraManager has not been initialized
at com.example.myflashlight.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:33)                                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)                                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)                                                                                                     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)

I tried to google so far but didn't find any solution. This is the official document but trying using this method didn't help either.  Not sure how to control the flashlight light brightness strength.

https://source.android.com/docs/core/camera/torch-strength-control

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace clearly says that cameramanager object is not initialized and it is NULL.
Call the API after below line

cameraManager = getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
cameraManager.turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel(cameraId, 50)

Also it is recommended to check the characteristic availability of the camera feature before calling it. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#FLASH_INFO_STRENGTH_MAXIMUM_LEVEL